# Why am I getting ERROR: column "GLOBE-BE-154" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, insert

I create a Table in a Database and looks as following

```
test1=# SELECT * FROM stunden_Plan;
 stunde | montag | dienstag | mittwoch | donnerstag | freitag 
--------+--------+----------+----------+------------+---------
      1 |        |          |          |            |
(1 row)
```

From this distinction, I wanted to insert some values into the table below...

```
INSERT INTO stunden_Plan (stunde, montag, dienstag, mittwoch, donnerstag, freitag)
VALUES (2, "GLOBE-BE-154", "CH-SCH-156", "D-KR-477", "M-HA-477", "E-ZE-477" );
```

But I got an error of which I have no understanding!

```
ERROR:  column "GLOBE-BE-154" does not exist
```

I am grateful for any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) string constants need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL

```
INSERT INTO stunden_Plan (stunde, montag, dienstag, mittwoch, donnerstag, freitag)
VALUES (2, 'GLOBE-BE-154', 'CH-SCH-156', 'D-KR-477', 'M-HA-477', 'E-ZE-477' );
```

Double quotes are for [identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)